# Maximal subgroups of finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Are the maximal subgroups of a finite group always conjugate? Suppose that $H$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$. Consider a subgroup $H$ conjugate to any element of $G$, this subgroup has the same order as $H$, hence max is maximal and all maximal subgroups are conjugate. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Consider the group $S_4$. Then, $A_4$ and $S_3$ are maximal subgroups of $S_4$ but they have different orders.

Comment: Smallest counterexample is $S_3$; the maximal subgroups are the proper subgroups, one of order $3$ and three of order $2$; the latter cannot be conjugate to the former. In addition, if all maximal subgroups were conjugate, then you would never be able to have a normal maximal subgroup unless the maximal subgroup were a unique maximal subgroup... and the only finite groups with a unique maximal subgroup are cyclic of prime power order. Finally, maximality is not determined by the order. So, “not just no, but hell no.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All conjugates of maximal subgroups are maximal, but not all maximal subgroups are conjugate of each other. They don't even need to be the same order: take a product of two cyclic groups of orders two different primes.